# What is /dev/blog?

Tags: linux, suse, dev

I have tried searching for /dev/blog on google, duckduckgo, etc.; but I cannot find any information about it. I've also asked another sysadmin where I work, but he didn't know what it is used for either. Is there anywhere I can find documentation that would tell me more about this? This is on a SLES 11 system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/blog` from what I have been able to find refers to `libblogger` which is a library for boot logging.

References:

http://www.pynix.org/webcvs/index.cgi/AppKit/basesystem/sysvinit/AppKit/libblogger.h?view=log&sortby=author&pathrev=ak21cd

http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/12.3/x86_64/sysvinit-tools-2.88+-83.2.1.x86_64.html